# Dynamically create a funtion with variable number of statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I know exec and eval are not recommended most of the time, but I want to dynamically create a function with variable number of statements. The reason I want to do this is because spawning 3 functions with 1 statement each has worse performance than one 1 function with 3 statements.

Basically I have some objects and will read the fields and objects from input.

For a variable amount of objs I want to assemble a single function for them, instead of creating many manual functions. Is there way to avoid 
(Or is there a way to generate make_funcN?)

```
def make_func1( obj1, field1, obj2, field2 ):
  def copy():
    obj1.__setattr__( field1, obj2.__getattribute__( field2 ) )
  return copy

def make_func2( obj1, field1, obj2, field2, \
                obj3, field3, obj4, field4 ):
  def copy():
    obj1.__setattr__( field1, obj2.__getattribute__( field2 ) )
    obj3.__setattr__( field3, obj4.__getattribute__( field4 ) )
  return copy

def make_func3( ... ):
  ...
```

Thanks,

Comment: "spawning 3 functions with 1 statement each has worse performance than one 1 function with 3 statements" is likely a true statement. But unless you are using this function, very, very heavily, the performance difference is unlikely to matter—especially when balanced against the additional complexity involved in doing this in a language that doesn't support native macros.

Comment: Yes I'm using this function very heavily ....

Comment: Well, make sure you benchmark the alternate approaches, then. If performance really matters, optimization base on data is greatly superior to guesses about what might be faster. Especially when the optimized version depends on metaprogramming and contains its own function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what the OP asked for. Instead of creating a series of similar attribute-copy functions that differ primarily in [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity), I present a few simple functions and the  "null hypothesis" for this problem: that creating multiple similar functions is well-intentioned, but not an effective optimization for this situation.

The simplest approach would be a single copy function, iterated over as many times as you have fields to set:

```py
def copyattr(obj1, field1, obj2, field2):
     setattr(obj1, field1, getattr(obj2, field2))
```

Call that as many times as needed to set all the attributes you like.
It's simple, Pythonic, and based on benchmarks I've run, performs very well.

If you instead want a flat list of copy instructions (suggested by your extended argument lists), then:

```py
def copyattrs(*args):
    for i in range(0, len(args), 4):
        setattr(args[i], args[i+1], getattr(args[i+2], args[i+3]))
```

Will do the trick. It takes an arbitrarily long flat sequence of parameters in the same order as before. Several of the answers that hand back `copy()` functions with embedded loops are basically this, except requiring a setup step (`make_func()`) and transmitting parameters through a closure.

If you're using just Python 3, you can shave a few nanoseconds with extended argument unpacking syntax:

```py
def copyattrs(*args):
    for i in range(0, len(args), 4):
        setattr(*args[i:i+2], getattr(*args[i+2:i+4]))
```

But no variants I tried--including generating copy functions of specific arity--made much difference in this task. Based on Python data handling semantics, none of these approaches copies much data. They all copy pointers, not large data sets, and that's remarkably efficient almost any way you do it. Much of the effort is consumed with parameter construction and access, and function call setup/teardown than into raw data copies. I had to run vast numbers of copies—1,000,000 to 20,000,000—to even start to take interesting amounts of time. Even the full benchmark run of 200,000,000 attribute copies only took a few seconds. And that included the full dataset copy needed to reset test state to ground zero each time.

Long story short, there seems little advantage in this "create a dynamic attribute copy function" approach. It's a useful experiment, but none of the benchmarks I ran showed a significantly faster result—especially if you take into account (as you should) the time needed to create the custom attribute copier function and then later marshal arguments into it. There's also a potentially material overhead to generating and keeping around a large number of closures live in memory, depending on how those are used. In scenarios I ran, the closures-driven parameterless `copy()` in fact benchmarked the worst. (For larger arities, horrifically slower.)

Eminent computer scientists CAR Hoare and Donald Knuth famously argued "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." So before you resort to fancy optimizations, make sure you know where the real performance issues lie, and that your proposed solution is, in fact, an improvement. [Ned Batchelder nails this](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200604/five_truths_about_code_optimization.html):

> … "you don't know where the problem is." I can't remember how many times I've gone in with a nifty idea about speeding things up, tried it, and it didn't work.

The article he's referring to, Russ Olsen's [Five Truths about Optimization](http://www.jroller.com/rolsen/entry/five_truths_about_code_optimization), is a solid read and good guidance on speeding things up. For a masterful book-length how-to, try Jon Bentley's *Writing Efficient Programs*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on comparison of these list based approaches. As you mentioned they don't have much difference. I think what I meant in the beginning is really to generate a function that doesn't have a loop "for i in range(0, len(args), 4):". Instead I imagined this to be flattened into a couple of statements for each function. I experimented and this is indeed faster to copy 3 vars in 1 function versus 1 var in 3 functions. But you might be correct that I shouldn't resort to python for this performance critical task

Comment: I tested billions of iterations through randomly generated data. Was there a difference when doing this kind of [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)? Yes. Was it a big win? The sort of thing that would make your program overall faster? No. In fact, some of the unrolling (when used with closures was much, much worse). But as always, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should use the builtin [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) instead of `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__`; do not trade miniature performance gains for readability.

Then, you can group your `args` into fours and then set and get the attributes for each pair of objects accordingly:

```
def make_func(*args):
   if len(args) % 4 != 0:
       raise ValueError("number of arguments must be a multiple of 4")
   def copy():
       for i in range(0, len(args), 4):
           setattr(args[i], args[i+1], getattr(args[i+2], args[i+3]))
   return copy
```

Comment: I read online and `__getattribute__` is basically doing fewer jobs than getattr. I experimented with timeit and found that `__getattribute__` is faster than getattr.

Comment: That's because the builtins will call those behind the scenes, but bear in mind that Python isn't all about micro-optimisations. **Code readability** is strongly emphasized by the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_func1(*args):
    assert len(args) % 4 == 0

    def copy():
        for i in range(0, len(args), 4):
            obj1, field1, obj2, field2 = args[i:i + 4]
            obj1.__setattr__(field1, obj2.__getattribute__(field2))

    return copy
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thanks, wasn't thinking right, corrected the range.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass in the objects and fields as list or tuples:

```
def make_func(to_objs, to_fields, from_objs, from_fields):
    def copy():
        for to_obj, to_field, from_obj, from_field in zip(to_obj, to_fields, 
                                                          from_objs, from_fields):
            to_obj.__setattr__(to_field, from_obj.__getattribute__(from_field))
    return copy
```